# Dynamic Column and Row In datagrid in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I need dynamic column and row in Data Grid in react JS.

Here is my code.

```
    let response_data = {initial_data: [
    {
      "id":1,
      "Did I see this plant in 2016?":"No",
      "Did I see this plant in 2017?":"Yes",
      "How Many?":1,
      "User Data 4":"x",
      "User Data 5":'nil',
      "Did I see this plant in 2022?":"No",
      "Name":"Abronia alpina"
      },
     {
      "id":2,
      "Did I see this plant in 2016?":"No",
      "Did I see this plant in 2017?":"No",
      "How Many?":11,
      "User Data 4":"x",
      "User Data 5":'nil',
      "Did I see this plant in 2022?":"Yes",
      "Name":"Abronia alpina1"
     }
   ]
   };

  let row = response_data.initial_data
  let columns = Object.keys(response_data.initial_data).map((key, id)=>{
   [{
    field: key,
    headerName: key,
    width: 100
   }]
  })

return{
  <DataGrid
          components={{ Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar }}
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={pageSize}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
          autoHeight={true}
          onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
          pagination
          componentsProps={{
            toolbar: {
              value: searchText,
              onChange: (event) =>
                requestSearch(event.target.value),
              clearSearch: () => requestSearch(""),
            },
          }}
        />
}
```

I need column and row should be dynamic, not static using react JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *getRowHeight* property of data grid to dynamic height and *flex* for dynamic column.

```
<dataGrid
  column={[{ field: 'username', flex: 0.5 }, { field: 'age', flex: {0.5} }]}
  tableRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
/>
```

[Column dynamic width](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-dimensions/#fluid-width)
[Dynamic Row Height](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-height/#dynamic-row-height)